# Chrome Violation when using document.write with generated iFrame source - alternative?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, document.write

I understand using document.write is discouraged for various reasons, however I'm using it to inject programmatically html generated into an iframe widget.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
document.body.appendChild(iframe)
iframe.contentWindow.document.open()
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(generateHtml())
iframe.contentWindow.document.close()
```

This method works perfectly for my use case, however Chrome warns against document.write as you'd expect: `[Violation] Avoid using document.write().`

Is it possible to suppress or satisfy the warning or do I have to live with it?

I believe it's the best method to inject html to an iframe, considering other ways that I have tried:

- Setting the src directly with `data:text/html; ...` - limitations around length
- Setting srcdoc with html - This is my fall back, but browser support could be an issue
- Encode html using btoa base64 and set src directly with `data:text/html;base64,...` - This didn't encode properly and yielded `Invalid regular expression: Range out of order in character class`

Appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more method is to create a `document` from `html` with [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), then patch the `iframe` document with that:

```
const html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Hello</title>
        </head>
        <body>World!</body>
    </html>
`;
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const docOld = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    const docNew = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    docOld.insertBefore(docNew.doctype, docOld.firstChild);
    docOld.replaceChild(docNew.documentElement, docOld.documentElement);
});
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Fantastic, this should work perfectly

Comment: Looks like `docNew.documentElement` is null in FF

Comment: Firefox is a bit slow, the `load` event is not so fast as in Chrome. Fixed it, now it should work in Firefox too.

Comment: Explains the flicker during load! Thanks for your time, much appreciated.